# Does `tmux` support any help documentation through command-mode like `vim`s `:help`?

Tags: linux, tmux

Does `tmux` support any help documentation through command-mode (`C-b :`) like `vim`'s `:help`?

I often want to display help documentation for a particular `tmux` command, say `kill-window`,  including at least the command's parameters.

Can I display such information in `tmux` without consulting the `man` page or online documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, although you could easily bind a key to split the window and show the manual.

If you are on OpenBSD with mandoc+less tags, something like this:

```
command-prompt -p'help:' 'splitw "man tmux"; send ":t%%" Enter'
```

Or maybe something like this on other platforms:

```
command-prompt -p'help:' 'splitw "man tmux"; send "/^ *%% \\[" Enter'
```

Or even this perhaps:

```
tmux command-prompt -p'help:' 'splitw "links https://man.openbsd.org/tmux#%%"'
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm on Linux or OSX. Can you describe what this command does to a novice `tmux` user: `command-prompt -p'help:' 'splitw "man tmux"; send "/^ *%% \\[" Enter'`? I'm especially confused about the `"/^ *%% \\["` part.

Comment: Also, to bind the command, what is the difference between `bind <key>` and `bind -T prefix <key>`? (sorry for off-topic question)

Comment: The command asks you for a string (with the prompt "help:"), then it runs the command in the second part which first uses `split-window` to split the current window, then it uses `send-keys` to send the keys to less which ask it to search for the bit you typed (the %% is replaced by what you entered at the prompt). The bit surrounding the %% is a regular expression which looks for where the command is described (it has spaces before and ` [` after). `bind-key` without `-Tprefix` binds the key in the root table which means you don't need top press the prefix key (by default `C-b`) to run it.